# Silverlight - Debugging the application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am working on Silverlight application, which is just a component in a much larger application. I am rewriting the funcionality using HTML5/JS. I really need to be able to debug it.

I am using VS2010. Problem is that I can't debug the application, actually only Silverlight (Silverlight 5) application. Other parts of the application can be debugged normally.

I have tried All browsers:
- Safari
- Chrome
- Firefox
- IE (JFC)

This Silverlight component, nowdays only works with Firefox. My PC is running Windows 10, and with the Edge, Silverlight is not working at all. I tried setting compability mode in IE, but does not help.
Reading some posts, I come to the conclusion that I should install older versions of IE (10) that support Silverlight, and can trigger the brakepoints.

If that is correct, where can I install Internet Explorer 10 for Windows 10?

Outside the topic... is it only me, or this whole concept with Silverlight and browsers is rotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable debugging for Silverlight, navigate to **Properties** for the Web project that is hosting the Silverlight application.  Select the **Web** tab and make sure that the Silverlight is checked under **Debuggers**

[image]